# GTA V heists face bandanas

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

So heists are finally here in GTA Online. With this update came a lot of new masks. I know myself and many other players have asked R* to put in face bandanas. Now they're here, but you are forced to wear a hat with them, and i just want the face bandana. I've removed it before but it comes back when I enter a new game. Is there any way to permanently remove the hat?

Answer (score 1):

No you don't, go to a clothes store, remove glasses and hat, then save it as a custom outfit. It will reset back to the hat, so just switch to the saved outfit.

Comment: Some punctuation and sentences would be nice.